# NodeJS exports not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm having problems with nodeJS export understanding... I'll explain the problem:

I'm trying to export a variable which is in my /bin/www file to my index.js file:

**/bin/www**

```
   #!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('chat:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http).listen(server);
module.exports.io = io;
console.log("FROM WWW FILE: " + exports.io);



/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

and im trying to get that variable inside index.js:

**index.js**

```
   var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var www = require('../bin/www');

console.log("FROM INDEX.JS WWW OBJECT:" + www);

console.log("WWW.IO VARIABLE FROM INDEX.JS:" + www.io); //UNDEFINED ?

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

//io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 // console.log("CONEXION ESTABLECIDA");
  //socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  //socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
   // console.log(data.my);
  //});
//});



module.exports = router;



console.log("IO IS:" + www.io); //UNDEFINED ?
```

Im not sure why www.io is undefined, I'm sure is pretty obvious but can't get why...

If you could give me a helping hand i'd appreciate.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Are you sure you are passing a correct path here: `require('../bin/www')` ?

Comment: console.log(www) says [Object object] so i assume something is getting... but not sure why i can't take the export. By the way I'm not so sure why www isnt www.js ... because express generator made www without www.

Comment: i tested only the export/import part of your code and it works flawlessly. You either got the path wrong inside your require or io is undefined.

Comment: I don't know why but this is what log is saying: 

http://imgur.com/byoDmff

I think it's a problem about executing order but doesn't make alot of sense because the server executes before the index.js petition... I don't know is kind of strange.

Comment: I edited the original post to show the original files, it might be because www file is not a '.js' file... not sure

Comment: is app.js requiring index.js again and bin/www the entry point of your application?